# Bind events to an image with a canvas on top

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an image in a HTML document with an absolutely positioned Canvas element on top of it, to allow me to draw over the image. This may seem like bad practice, but I am also using a JavaScript library that adds effects to the image when you mouse over it. For this reason, I cannot simply draw the image to the canvas.

However, having the Canvas in front breaks the JavaScript library, as the image is no longer generating mouse-over events.

Is there any way of having these two bits of functionality simultaneously?

(If needed, I can specify exactly what my problem is, but answers are more useful when they are generic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Creating_and_triggering_events) with [initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) to manually launch event on image.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it bind events to canvas and then pragmatically track if the cursor within the bound of image...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I set the image as the css background of the canvas, then had a transparent png over the top to bind events to and track movement.

I also ended up modifying the library to my own needs, as I couldn't find another way.